# Will life exist on Earth if it stops rotation?

Tags: astronomy

Rotation is ubiquitous in the cosmos. Planets rotate, as do stars and galaxies. This comes about simply from [conservation of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_angular_momentum). What if Earth stops [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation) ? How does it effect on [living beings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organism)?

I am not talking about [Earth's revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_orbit).

Comment: Does it stop immediately, or does it slow down gradually and then stop?  Does it stop rotating relative to the sun, or relative to something else?  VTC until this question is a bit more clear.

Comment: Maybe after a period of stillness Earth will probably start rotating again, thanks to our moon pulling on the ocean unless you want everything to stop in-situ then can someone turn on the bat signal in the day otherwise it won't be my turn to save wb ;D

Comment: I think we really need to know how it stopped rotating, what caused it, and why. The energy that it would take would have significant effect on a lot of things besides just the Earth's rotation. Was this energy all concentrated in one spot (like a meteor strike) or was it distributed over the entire Earth (like some form of electromagnetic brake)?

Comment: I assume you're not talking about the XKCD [link](https://io9.gizmodo.com/xkcds-creator-explains-what-would-happen-if-earth-stopp-1625068208). How is your question different?

Comment: @user6760 The moon doesn't just pull on the Earth's oceans, it pulls on the Earth itself. It's just that the oceans are made of water, so they move more obviously.

Comment: Do you mean stop rotating entirely, or become tidally locked to the sun?  (So it rotates once a year, keeping one side always facing the sun.)

Comment: Would be helpful to have a timeline. Do you want to know what would happen over what time? Immediately after? Years? Centuries? Millions of years?
Also does it suddenly stop, or does it slow down to an alt over the course of millions or billions of years?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it happened suddenly, there would be no life left.

Quoting Dr. Sten Odenwald:

> If the Earth stopped spinning suddenly, the atmosphere would still be in motion with the Earth's original 1100 mile per hour rotation speed at the equator. All of the land masses would be scoured clean of anything not attached to bedrock. This means rocks, topsoil, trees, buildings, your pet dog, and so on, would be swept away into the atmosphere.

And again:

> If the Earth stopped rotating, it's magnetic field would no longer be regenerated and it would decay away to some low, residual value due to the very small component which is 'fossilized' in its iron-rich rocks. [...] This is a significant biohazard.

There's also to consider the change in temperature, having 6 months of day and 6 months of night. On Earth we currently see that only in the polar regions. Life still exists in those areas, especially marine life.

**One important note:** their climate depends not only on the 6 months light cycle, but also on their angle relative to the sunlight. That's to say that not all Earth would look like that.

Quoting Dr Karl Kruszelnicki:

> Life could continue in a narrow twilight zone between the hot and cold halves. But this twilight zone would slowly creep around the planet over the period of a year, as the Earth did its annual orbit around the Sun.

And again:

> The liquid water in the oceans is far more mobile and responsive to forces. So the Earth's spin has pushed up this liquid water to an 'abnormal' elevation of about eight kilometres. [...] So take away the spin and you take away all water at the equator. [...] The water that left the equatorial regions would have to go somewhere, and that 'somewhere' would be the poles. There would be two totally disconnected polar oceans on each side of the equatorial mega-continent.

All of this points to a very bad scenario for life on earth. The change, being so sudden, would kill pretty much everything.

If Earth gradually slowed down to a halt, over billions of years, then life has a chance. Animals could migrate over million of years and life in general would evolve to survive these changes. Temperatures would still be an issue, especially in the 6 months of day, but underground cave systems and oceans would likely still have plenty of life, being a safe refuge from the extreme temperatures of the surface.

EDIT: Added quote sources:
https://image.gsfc.nasa.gov/poetry/ask/q1168.html
https://www.australiangeographic.com.au/blogs/dr-karl-need-to-know/2018/05/what-would-happen-if-our-planet-stopped-spinning-entirely/

EDIT 2: As pointed out in the comments, for forgot a pretty important point: if Earth didn't have a magnetic field anymore, we would lose our main source of shielding from radiation. As a secondary effect, the Earth's atmosphere would probably be gone too, although I'm not sure how long this would take. For more info about that, I suggest checking out this article and its sources: https://whatifshow.com/what-if-earths-magnetic-field-disappeared/
I still believe it would be possible for some form of life to survive in closed cave systems, but that's my own hypothesis and I don't have any data to support it.

EDIT 3: Clarification: as pointed out in the comments, life wouldn't be completely gone. Major life forms would, but microbial life might still survive; stuff like bacteria and such can be found very deep underground, and might not be affected in a significant manner by this change.

Comment: As a further clarification, wouldn't the practically disappeared magnetosphere cause more radiation to flood onto the Earth, essentially killing most surface life and life close to the surface of the water? Regardless of fast or slow change? In addition, no Northern lights anymore.

Comment: all due respect to your sourcem but "So the Earth's spin has pushed up this liquid water to an 'abnormal' elevation of about eight kilometres" is utter nonsense. Yes the earth is an oblate spheroid due to rotation, but the ocean is lifted *exactly* as much as the rock under it. Sealevel at the equator **will not** drop 8 km.

Comment: This is a good answer. It could become an awesome answer with links to those quotes ;)

Comment: Randall Monroe also answers this question in the book _What If?_ Without buying the book, the answer can be found here: https://io9.gizmodo.com/xkcds-creator-explains-what-would-happen-if-earth-stopp-1625068208

Comment: It begs the question be asked, 'Does whatever force that stopped the earth from spinning apply to everything, equally, or just the mantle, or the core, or what?" If the crust suddenly stopped spinning, wouldn't all of the oceans continue their momentum and scour the land?  Methinks that would be worse than glaciation.

Comment: @PcMan   See https://planet-earth-2017.com/sea-level/ for support of the idea that the sea bulge at the equator is due to spin. Graphs and calculations depict the level change with every degree of spin increase or decrease, and historical geological evidence and results of past changes.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Done, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Trioxidane You're right. If we lost the magnetic field, we would not only be bombarded with radiations, but our atmosphere would likely be stripped away. So yeah, no life left.

Comment: @PcMan Additional support that global warming will result in higher sea levels at the equator, lower levels at the poles, because of the Earth' spin. https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/melting-polar-ice-will-spike-sea-levels-at-the-equator-24739579/

Comment: @PcMan Water isn't going to stay on a mountain just because the land is higher... The mountains stay mountains because they are solid (plus or minus a few landslides, perhaps some catastrophic settling/earthquakes) but the water is mostly going to go towards flat (flat being minimum potential energy) (plus or minus a few waves and tides and things). Btw, 8km is interesting. Sea level at the equator is ~21km further from the center than sea level at the poles, but it seems like if you rearrange everything evenly you get an 8km drop at the equator and a 13km rise at the poles (b/c trig?).

Comment: Regarding the magnetic field, Venus shows us that the atmosphere won't be lost without magnetic field. There will be accelerated loss of water to space, that is true, but even in the worst case scenario it will take millions of years for the Earth to lose all its water. In addition, loss of Earth's rotation may not mean complete loss of Earth's core rotation - but this point needs to be confirmed with the OP.

Comment: @user3067860 nope. at continent scale , the mountains and rock of the crust are mere scum floating on a huge ocean of mantle. They will almost instantly conform to the new gravity potential line, if you remove centrifugal 'force' of rotation. (you would get some really *stupendous* earthquakes as the settling happens, of course). Yes on you 8km and 13km. but at planet scales mantle fluids is just as liquid and splashy as ocean water is, and crust-mountains mere scum floating on top, with no structural strength.

Comment: You're quite wrong about there being no life left, since there's life in the lithosphere: https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg20827874-800-life-is-found-in-deepest-layer-of-earths-crust/  Magnetic field and atmosphere are also probably irrelevant when you get a few hundred meters below the surface.

Comment: The mass of the atmosphere actually blocks radiation fairly well. We wouldn't all immediately be irradiated if the magnetic field disappears. The field weakens and disappears periodically when it flips, and these events are not associated with mass extinctions. Loss of atmosphere due to solar winds would occur on geologic timescales.

Comment: @jamesqf Thanks for pointing that out, added to *EDIT 3*.

Comment: @Alexander Venus According to the article linked  below, Venus has a magnetic field generated through the interaction between its atmosphere and solar winds. It's not as strong as ours, and this causes water and some gasses to be lost into space. This suggest that Earth's atmosphere as we know it would be lost or at least severely changed by the lack of Earth's magnetic field.
https://sci.esa.int/web/venus-express/-/50246-a-magnetic-surprise-for-venus-express

While the process might take a while, OP didn't specify a timeline. So I consider the loss of atmosphere a consequence worth noting

Comment: @Mr_Bober all right, this is down to semantic nuances :) "atmosphere as we know it would be lost" imho is not the same as "atmosphere would be lost". Actually only a small fraction of atmosphere would be lost over a billion years period. But yes, the loss of water will have a very dramatic effect.

Answer (score 3):

If Earth stop rotating on its own axis it would mean that a single solar day would last exactly as long as a year. That is, the Sun in the sky will move as the Earth orbits around it.

This would alter the weather patterns in a very drastic way: 6 months of light and 6 months of darkness everywhere on the planet are not something negligible.

I think most if not all of the lifeforms relying on the Sun for energy won't survive such a change. Probably some of the mosses and lichens growing in the subpolar regions would do just fine and might start migrating toward more temperate regions as soon as the ecologic niches are left available in habitable regions. They could then sustain some sort of food chain, which would be forced to either migrate chasing the sun or hibernate for the long night.

On the other hand non Sun dependent life will thrive undisturbed.

Comment: I think a key question would be the effect of prolonged "high noon" over parts of the Earth.  They would heat much more than any current desert.  While water that boiled could precipitate elsewhere, the effect of baking the landscape could be drastic - limestone could be slaked, coal and peat burned, greatly increasing greenhouse warming.  Which might not be regretted later that night...  I don't really know the answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

### **No**

If Earth stopped rotation it would mean it is essentially [tidally-locked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) with the sun. This would mean you would have once face that is always facing the sun and would be baking hot, and the other side would never get any sunlight and would be freezing cold. The only life that could survive would be in a minute "twilight zone" region between the two extremes. Even then, life might struggle to adapt because there would no longer be any day-night cycle and no more seasons.

The tides will also stop. It depends on whether you get rid of the moon or not, [because the presence of the moon would cause the earth to rotate on its own](https://blogs.agu.org/martianchronicles/2009/02/25/a-tidally-locked-earth/), though it would rotate much more slowly than it currently does.

The oceans would likely boil away or freeze due to the tidal locking, which would have disastrous consequences for whatever life survived in the twilight zone. [We would also probably lose the atmosphere.](https://www.seeker.com/what-if-earth-became-tidally-locked-1766440555.html) Long-term I would say there would also be problems with the minute amount of plant and planktonic life in the twilight zones maintaining enough oxygen in the Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: note that tidally locked bodies keep rotating, else they could not show the same face to the central body while orbiting it

Comment: Tidal locking requires a rotational period equal to the orbital period, not a total lack of rotation. A body which stopped rotating entirely could spontaneously become tidally locked, but it would take a very long time.

Comment: If the Earth stopped rotating due entirely to natural forces, the result would HAVE to be a tidally locked rotation. The only reason it would stop rotating completely is that it went PAST the equilibrium of a tidally locked rotation and some external force other than natural forces caused it to happen. Tidally locked is probably the inevitable destiny of Earth in the very long run, unless the Sun burns out or we are pulled into the Sun first.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Hmm, how do planets that rotate in retrograde fit in with that? They seem to have gone well past 1-to-1 and all the way into the negatives. (Venus in particular seems interesting, since it's retrograde and also has less than 1 Venus-day per Venus-year. Long term, do we expect it to rotate faster to reach a tidally-locked-retrograde rotation speed, or slow down, passing through 0, to ultimately reach tidally-locked-prograde rotation speed?)

Comment: @user3067860 What is your evidence that retrograde planets  have actually flipped their rotation all the way through '0'? Do you have evidence that Venus is NOT increasing rotational speed to tidally locked, if indeed it is now spinning at less than tidally locked rotation?  Are you saying that it could go right through tidally locked and then through 0 and into spinning in the opposite direction?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Well, please note my use of question marks. (Actually, some more searching reveals that really no one knows what Venus will do--or even has much precision about what it is doing now. Fun! It may be slowing down, or may just have a really inconsistent day length. If slowing down, it may eventually speed back up again before reaching 0.) I'm just trying to understand your assertion that it's impossible for Earth to go past 1-to-1 when we have an existent example of a planet that is between 0 and -1.

Comment: @user3067860 "Not every case of tidal locking involves synchronous rotation.[3] With Mercury, for example, this tidally locked planet completes three rotations for every two revolutions around the Sun, a 3:2 spin–orbit resonance....However, in this case the exact same portion of the body does not always face the partner on all orbits. There can be some shifting due to variations in the locked body's orbital velocity and the inclination of its rotation axis.' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking

Comment: @user3067860 Actually Venus MIGHT have reversed all the way through 0 and in the opposite direction, or might be slowing down, or might be speeding up.   https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-venus-spins-the-wrong/ But eventually all rotations become tidally locked. See the wikipedia article for the math.

Comment: @user3067860 My assertion is 'tidally locked', not 1:1. Tidally locked does NOT absolutely mean 1:1.